# why run the gpseginstall utility occured hostfile_exkeys is not accessible as user gpadmin?

Tags: database, greenplum

The GreenPlum version is 4.3.8

when I run the gpseginstall utility to create the Greenplum system user (gpadmin) on all hosts and set the password for that user on all hosts occured a error.

Several steps before installing gpseginstall are correct.
I think the reason should that gpadmin user not competence to read root's file,
so I chmod 777 to the file but the error still occured.
the command is gpseginstall -f hostfile_exkeys -u gpadmin -p gpadmin.
who can help me to solve the error.
Here is the picture.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Try moving the `hostfile_exkeys` file into `/tmp` and providing the full path to it when invoking `gpseginstall`:

```
gpseginstall -f /tmp/hostfile_exkeys -u gpadmin -p gpadmin
```